# Model Hierarchy In Php Phalcon - Can't Find Attribute of Parent Model When Accessing Child Model

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I am working on Php Phalcon, Xampp server. My model classes form an heirarchy.

I have a UsersAbstract class which has some generic attributes like Full_Name, Email_ID etc.
Then I have derived class UserOfficials which has more attributes like Occupation etc. Then I have a grandchild class (which inherits from UserOfficials) called OfficialDoctor.
UsersAbstract class is parent to UserPatients too.

When I wanted to access UsersAbstract and UserPatients, I used the following code:

```
$select_patient = "Select "
                            ."UserPatients.Patient_ID, "
                            ."UserPatients.Unique_ID, "
                            ."UsersAbstract.Full_Name, "
                            ."UsersAbstract.Age, "
                            ."UsersAbstract.Gender, "
                            ."UsersAbstract.City, "
                            ."UsersAbstract.Country FROM UserPatients JOIN UsersAbstract WHERE UsersAbstract.Unique_ID = UserPatients.Unique_ID "
                            ."And UsersAbstract.Availablity_Flag = 1";

        $patients = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($select_patient);
        $this->current_patient = $patients[0];
```

This worked beautifully. Now I want to access one attribute from UserOfficials and here is my code:

```
$id = $user->Unique_ID;
               $select_doctor = "Select UserOfficials.Occupation from UserOfficials WHERE UserOfficials.Unique_ID = :uid:";
               $occ = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($select_doctor, array("uid" => $id));
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usersabstract.Occupation' in 'field list'
```

My question is short - WHY? I am accessing the table UserOfficials not UsersAbstract.

Note:
My tables and corresponding classes are named as follows:

```
Class -------------- Table

UsersAbstract ------ UsersAbstract

UserOfficials ------ User_Officials

UserPatients ------- User_Patients
```

I know about the camel case names for corresponding database tables must but if one query works then why doesn't the other?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, I had to put single quotes around the name of the column i.e.

`$select_doctor = "Select UserOfficials.Occupation from UserOfficials WHERE UserOfficials.Unique_ID = :uid:"`;

After this, it gave no more errors.